# AWS Java SDK Context class not found

Tags: aws-java-sdk

I'm trying to develop a Lambda function using the AWS Java SDK and I'm running into a stumbling block.  The examples reference a `com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context` class, but I'm not able to find this anywhere in the Java SDK.  I have even downloaded the entire AWS Java SDK source code and ran `$ find . -name 'Context.java'` and it came up with no results....was this class deprecated and the documentation not updated?  Am I completely missing something?  I am using Maven to build the project and this is my POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>awstest</groupId>
    <artifactId>AWSLambdaTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.156</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Thank you

Comment: it seems like this class is found in aws-lambda-java-core library

Answer (score 1):

I found the context class in the following dependency

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```